# unsigned char array breaks at zero bytes in Azure Sphere SDK when passing to a function

Tags: c, azure-iot-hub, uart, rs485, azure-sphere

I am using **(1)**[Azure Sphere MT3620 Starter Kit](https://www.avnet.com/shop/us/products/avnet-engineering-services/aes-ms-mt3620-sk-g-3074457345636825680/) and **(2)**[RS485 CLICK 5V](https://www.mikroe.com/rs485-5v-click) and **(3)**[Geovan Board](https://www.geovan.com/board_kr/?ckattempt=2&mod=document&uid=469)

Here is the setup (I don't have latest picture, so #2 is swapped to first slot in the MT3620)

[image: hardware setup]

My **MT3620** is registered all good with Azure IoTHub and pushing all telemetry data to cloud. Now I am trying to sent some HEX commands from **MT3620** to **Geovan Board** via **RS485 CLICK 5V**

Here is my Calling code

```
//RS485 to Geovan to Update Registry values
unsigned char updateAllChannelData[] = { 0x01, 0x06, 0x00, 0x19, 0x00, 0x01, 0x99, 0xCD };
SendUartMessage(uartFd, updateAllChannelData, sizeof(updateAllChannelData));
delay(10);
//RS485 to Geovan to Read all channels 
unsigned char readAllChannel[] = { 0x01, 0x03, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x10, 0x15, 0xC6  };
SendUartMessage(uartFd, readAllChannel, sizeof(readAllChannel));
delay(1.5); //20
```

when data is passed to `SendUartMessage` both arrays (`updateAllChannelData` and `readAllChannel`) breaks at `0x00` so final command being passed to **Geovan Board** is incomplete and no response is received.

Here is **SendUartMessage** method

```
static void SendUartMessage(int uartFd, const char* dataToSend, size_t totalBytesToSend)
{
   // dataToSend breaks at 0x00 right here not after executing any lines below
   // First command array becomes {0x01, 0x06}
   // Second command array becomes {0x01, 0x03}
    size_t totalBytesSent = 0;
    int sendIterations = 0;
    close(r1PinFd);
    r1PinFd = GPIO_OpenAsOutput(MIKROE_PWM, GPIO_OutputMode_PushPull, GPIO_Value_High);
    while (totalBytesSent < totalBytesToSend) {
        sendIterations++;

        // Send as much of the remaining data as possible
        size_t bytesLeftToSend = totalBytesToSend - totalBytesSent;
        const char* remainingMessageToSend = dataToSend + totalBytesSent;
        ssize_t bytesSent = write(uartFd, remainingMessageToSend, bytesLeftToSend);
        if (bytesSent == -1) {
            Log_Debug("ERROR: Could not write to UART: %s (%d).\n", strerror(errno), errno);
            exitCode = ExitCode_SendMessage_Write;
            return;
        }

        totalBytesSent += (size_t)bytesSent;
    }
    int c, d;

    sleep(5);
    close(r1PinFd);
    r1PinFd = GPIO_OpenAsOutput(MIKROE_PWM, GPIO_OutputMode_PushPull, GPIO_Value_Low);

    Log_Debug("Sent %zu bytes over UART in %d calls.\n", totalBytesSent, sendIterations);
}
```

FYI: I have tested these commands as below

1. Connect Geovan directly to PC
2. using [Hercules SETUP utility](https://www.hw-group.com/software/hercules-setup-utility) open com port on which Geovan is connected
3. send HEX command "`0x01, 0x06, 0x00, 0x19, 0x00, 0x01, 0x99, 0xCD`" wait 10 seconds
4. send HEX command "`0x01, 0x03, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x10, 0x15, 0xC6`" wait 10 seconds
5. received expected response

This confirms from Geovan these commands as sent and responded correctly. So the challenge is sending same commands from **MT3620** through **RS485 CLICK 5V** to **Geovan Board**.

Can someone point out the what am I missing over here?

**Update:**
Before stepping in to function, this is how my array looks
[image]

After stepping in to the function, this is what it looks like
[image]

Comment: The `strlen` works on ***null**-terminated strings*. The *null* being the byte `0`. You need to pass the length of the data to the `SendUartMessage` function.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude but my array is changed even before code comes to strlen

Comment: What do you mean your "array is changed"? It's not changed. You clearly state that your program "breaks at `0x00`" which is *exactly* the behavior expected when you use `strlen` to get the length of something that isn't a string. Just *try* to pass `totalBytesToSend` as an argument to the function, and don't use `strlen` in the call.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude it has been long time since I coded C, but if you see my updated screenshots, data that is passed to the function is not full even before it reached to strlen(), I suspect this is related to Ninja compiler that is shipped with this SDK https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure-sphere/app-development/development-environment

Comment: What you see in the the debugger is that the debugger treats the data as a null-terminated string, because the type is `char *` and not `unsigned char *`. The array isn't *changed* or modified, it's just the null-terminator problem. And remember, you're passing a *pointer*, not an array. The debugger also doesn't know that the data points to the first element of an array with a fixed compile-time size, all it knows is the type (`char *`) and the where the pointer it pointing. The debugger then *assumes* that the data is a null-terminated string.